# Google login to Sulu CMS admin v2.5

Tags: reactjs, sulu

I would like to have Login via Google oAuth in Sulu CMS (version 2.5) admin.
How can I override login form to add Google login button in my project?

I found out that itself login form is here as React component inside AdminBundle:

vendor/sulu/sulu/src/Sulu/Bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/js/containers/Login/LoginForm.js

The source is here:
https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/2.5/src/Sulu/Bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/js/containers/Login/LoginForm.js

I wonder what is the way to override this component to change form on UI? Is there way to connect react-google-login?
Probably, server PHP part is out of this question scope but would be happy to receive some hints as well.

[image: sulu admin Login form]